# VS Profiler Start function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using a VS2010 Profiler and I have a problem with specifying a start point for profiling.
Namely, if a have FunctionB() which is called by FunctionA(), I want  only to profile a performance of a FunctionB() with all its subfunctions.

This is a sample code:

```
FunctionA()
{

  ... other functions, initializations, etc

    FunctionB()
}
```

At the moment I use this command:

```
vsinstr File.dll /start:outside,FunctionB
```

and I have a problem, because it is profiled something which is not needed (for other functions, initializations)

Any suggestions, please?